# How make a notification when app is closed

Tags: java, android, service

i want to make a notification when the app is closed.

Im new to Java and i dont now if a need a service or use AlarmManager.

My idea is to make a txt(in my server) with a number, if is 0 dont make the notifiacion, if is 1 make the notificacion and read all the content of other txt and use that text in the notificacion.

I need to check the txt with the number every 1 hour.

And i need this to happen even if the app is closed.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean a push notifcation or an internal notification??

Comment: What you're looking for in your specific question is an AlarmManager, but I would recommend instead looking into creating a push notification service through Firebase. This way, your app wouldn't have to continue to ping a webservice, but instead, would only get a notification if it needed to act.

Comment: You can use Alarm Manager for this schedule an alarm for every 1 hour with pending intent to a service class which will automatically call you service call every 1 hour, now do your backend call stuff in that service call and once you fetch data from your text file generate a notification using NotificationManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called push messaging I recommend looking at Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ or Amazon's implementation.

Comment: And what i need in the app and the server to make a push notification?

Comment: If you read through the documentation I linked they have a step by step guide to set up both the server and the app. I believe they even have a sample application you can look at.

Answer (score 0):

Services are exactly what you are looking for.

- They run in background
- Can be started again, even if the application is cleared from recent apps
- Can be timed to suit your requirements
- Very easy to implement

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is the official documentation.
And [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) can be a good start tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code for sending notification. But do not forget this, onStop method is also valid for clicking on home and recents button. So, whenever you click on home or recents button, a notification will pop up. You can improve this code by listening home and recents button.

```
 public void onStop() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon24)
            .setContentTitle("App Closed")
            .setContentText("You've closed the app")
            .setTicker("You've closed the app")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.icon96))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    super.onStop();
}
```